# Create dynamic download html link in cakephp 2.x with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.x

I have to create dynamic html download link but the filename and folder name I am getting in the jquery section. So how can I pass the $id and $filename from jquery to input field or is there any other way directly in jquery to create dynamic html link with cakephp.?

```
 <td class="broucher">
 <?php echo $this->Html->Link('',array('controller'=> "download",'action'=>"brochures",$id,$filename),array("download"=>'jpharma_footer.png','title'=>'Download','class'=>'brochureFile fa fa-download fa-fw '));   ?></td>
```

I was trying to Jquery for that but it's not working and getting error.

```
     var html='';
     var filename=ui.item.brouchersFile;
     var id=ui.item.brouchersId;
     html = '<?php echo $this->Html->Link("",array("controller"=> "download","action"=>"brochures",${id},${filename}),array("class"=>"fa fa-download fa-fw","download"=>${filename},"title"=>"Download"));  ?>' ;
     $(elmt).find(".broucher").append("<span class='msgspan'>html</span>");
```

Comment: You want to display `$id` and `$filename` in `<a>` or want to add it to href ?

Comment: @KiranShahi I want echo $this->Html->Link with $id and $filename

Comment: Suspect your issue is here: `"<span class='msgspan'>html</span>"` Think it should be: `"<span class='msgspan'>" + html + "</span>"`

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish or do. Also, why the `jquery-ui` tag? If you have the `$id` and `$filename` in PHP, you can just make a `<input>` element with those in PHP.  This is not a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. So your code looks like as follows.

```
var html='';
var filename=ui.item.brouchersFile;
var id=ui.item.brouchersId;
html = `<a href="link">/download/brochures/${id}/${filename}</a>`;
$(elmt).find(".broucher").append(`<span class='msgspan'>${html}</span>`);
```

Comment: Url shuld look like this /polymererp-development/download/brochures/8/jpharma_footer.png But I am getting the /polymererp-development/MarketingCampaigns/add that is the default add.ctp page

Comment: I am trying this but getting unexpected identifier error.                                html = '<?php echo $this->Html->Link("",array("controller"=> "download","action"=>"brochures",${id},${filename}),array("class"=>"fa fa-download fa-fw","download"=>${filename},"title"=>"Download")); ?>'